# Identify XPath from particular element

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I'm working on a page, where page loads dynamically and the data gets added while scrolling. To identify the properties of an item, I identified the parent div, where to identify the address, I have to locate an XPath from the parent to span element.
Below is my DOM structure:

```
<div class = "parentdiv">
    <div class = "search">
    <div class="header">
    <div class="data"></div>
    <div class="address-data">
      <div class="address" itemprop="address">
        <a itemprop="url" href="/search/Los-Angeles-CA-90025">
                <span itemprop="streetAddress">
                    Avenue
                </span>

                <br>
                <span itemprop="Locality">Los Angeles</span>
                <span itemprop="Region">CA</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here I want to locate the three spans, where I' currently in parent div.
Can someone guide how to locate an element using XPath from particular div?

Comment: Can you sum up the exact manual steps you are trying to Automate?

Comment: @DebanjanB, Actually I want to retrieve few values within this div(Likely I will iterate it through the web page).
I fetched the entire div (outer to the parent div) through,
`ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> MapCollection => FindElements(By.CssSelector("div.parentid"));`

Now I iterate over this collection and fetch the values i need through Getattribute. Now the values I required are found inside the span which i mentioned in the question. 
So how to get those span elements from where currently I am (in Parent div)

Comment: Great, so you want the list of `<span>` tagged `WebElements` with texts like `Avenue` with respect to `div class = "parentdiv"` node, am I right?

Comment: Yep! You got it right.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following XPaths,

To locate the street address:

```
//div[@class="parentdiv"]/div/div/a/span[@itemprop="streetAddress"]
```

To locate the locality/city:

```
//div[@class="parentdiv"]/div/div/a/span[@itemprop="Locality"]
```

To locate the state:

```
//div[@class="parentdiv"]/div/div/a/span[@itemprop="Region"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your DOM might become fairly large, since it adds elements while scrolling, so using CSS selectors might be quicker.

To get all the `span` tags in the div, use:

```
div[class='address'] span
```

To get a specific `span` by using the `itemprop` attribute use:

```
div[class='address'] span[itemprop='streetAddress']
div[class='address'] span[itemprop='Locality']
div[class='address'] span[itemprop='Region']
```

You can store the elements in a variable like so:

```
var streetAddress = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[class='address'] span[itemprop='streetAddress']"));
var locality = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[class='address'] span[itemprop='Locality']"));
var region = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[class='address'] span[itemprop='Region']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the list of `<span>` tagged `WebElements` with texts like `Avenue` with respect to `div class = "parentdiv"` node you can use the following block of code :

```
IList<IWebElement> myList = Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div.parentdiv > div.address > a[itemprop=url] > span"));
foreach (IWebElement element in myList) 
{
    string my_add = element.GetAttribute("innerHTML");
    Console.WriteLine(my_add);
}
```

Comment: Actually this fetches the text inside the span elements, but I wanted to store all the three span elements into different variable. Is that possible?

Comment: The strings are within a `List` now, you can do what ever you wish traversing the `List` through index. I think your original question **`Identify XPath from particular element`** got addressed through **`list of <span> tagged WebElements with texts like Avenue with respect to div class = "parentdiv" node`**. Please Accept the Answer.